# Does the CFTC have authority over all forms of "prediction markets"?

Tags: finance, gambling, cftc

I've been reading over previous cases that the [Commodity Futures Trading Commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodity_Futures_Trading_Commission) (CFTC) have brought up against organizations like [InTrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrade). From what I can tell, [InTrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrade) was brought under scrutiny because they created binary options for commodities over which the CFTC has authority, e.g., oil, gold, and economic performance indices.

**Would the CFTC also have similar jurisdiction on all forms of event contracts?**

For example, if there were a binary option on whether or not SpaceX's next rocket launch is successful, would that come under similar scrutiny?